# Maximum value and the number of occurrences in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, max

I'm having issues in a basic program about the maximum value of an array and its number of occurrences. I don't get how the program is getting compiled. I've tested it on paper and (compiled in Visual Studio), if I give at most ten values it works fine, but if I exceed ten numbers in the array, the count is acting crazy.

Here is the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i, v[50], max, count = 0;
    cout << "Number of elements = "; cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "v[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    max = v[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)     
        if (max < v[i]) {
            max = v[i];
            count = 0;
        }
        else 
            ++count;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Maximum value, " << max << ", occurs " << count << " times.";
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first advice, place your for loop in a braces

Comment: Did that, thank you for the hint, but still won't output the correct result.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second `for` loop you check if the current item in the array is bigger than the current biggest; if it's true you make the new maximum the current item and set the `count` to 0 - you should actually set it to 1. If it isn't bigger you increment the count - that's another problem. If the current number is less than the maximum and not equal to it you shouldn't incement the `count` variable, but that's what your code does.

Here is an easy fix that should work:

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, v[50], max, count = 0;
    cout << "Number of elements = "; cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "v[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    max = v[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)     
        if (max < v[i]) {
            max = v[i];
            count = 1;
        }
        else if(max == v[i])
            ++count;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Maximum value, " << max << ", occurs " << count << " times.";
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @Angel you got to make sure that the count doesn't start from 0. imagine this array 5,1,8,8 this will only print 8 with only 1 accurances.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should check that `n` is less than 50. You should also add braces around single statements to avoid bugs.

You also have an issue as `count` should be set to `1`, not `0`, and you should only increase it if you encounter the same number.

The C++ way: `max = *std::max_element(v, v+n);` and `count = std::count(v, v+n, max);`.

Comment: `n` is less that 50. Look, for the array: " 1 2 3 5 8 5 8 6 8 " (n = 9), the maximum value is `8`, so it should output `occurs 3 times`, but he actually outputs `4 times`. I've placed braces over all conditions too, but it still doesn't output correctly. I also didn't get what's the last code you wrote, sir, I'm sorry.

Comment: Made it work, thank you for the advice. Forgot to place the `if (max == v[i])`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i, v[50], max, count = 0;
    cout << "Number of elements = "; cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "v[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    map<int, int> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++m[v[i++]]);

    if (!m.empty())
    {
        const pair<int, int> p = *m.rbegin();

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Maximum value, " << p.first 
             << ", occurs " << p.second << " times.";
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```